# http-only cookie being set only after some time delay (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, user-agent, cookie-httponly

i see some weird behavior with **http-only** cookie - if i make subsequent request, the set-cookie header sent from the backend is not sent properly on the next request.

for example i tried it even via chrome dev tools console:

```
for (let i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    
setTimeout(()=>fetch("https://auth-stg.mydomain.com/api/auth/login/refresh?attemptingLogin=true", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not A(Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"121\", \"Chromium\";v=\"121\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
}),250*(i+1));    
}
```

cookies are being set - but every other request gets the previous cookie
e.g:

req1: request headers: cookie: refresh-token=0, response headers: set-cookie: refresh-token=1

req2: request headers: cookie: refresh-token=0, response headers: none (invalid refresh token)

req3: request headers: cookie: refresh-token=1, response headers: set-cookie: refresh-token=2
......

if for example i increase the setTimeout from 250 -> 1000 , all requests use the subsequent set-cookie and works as intended.

any idea why this happens? and is it normal behaviour?
causes me some issues regarding authentication when token expires and i refresh it and then retry the original request.

Thanks!

i believed set-cookie header should taking effect immediately and be used for the next request properly.

Comment: The most logical explanation is that it takes a bit for the response to be received / processed, a little after the _next_ request is already sent. If the server takes 250ms to respond this would always happen.

Comment: nice, so what would you think would be a proper solution?

Comment: Wait for the response to get back before firing off a new request?

Comment: oh i mean in real app i do have await on the request and i do get the response - it still reproduces, i consider setting some timeout

Comment: No you need to fire the next request *after* the last one is done. Adding `await` doesn't do this if you fire off requests in a loop with setTimeout.